# Connection problems with the socket.io-client to socket.io server 0.9.6

Tags: java, android, websocket, socket.io

I have a problem with my socket.io code for android.

The Server uses socket.io 0.9.6
On android I'm using socket-io-client-0.1.3.jar and engine-io-client.0.2.3.jar from [nkzawa](https://github.com/nkzawa)

After the connection to `myChannel` a `myConnect` is emitted. Afterwards I always get  a "something_changed" message if something changes with the new values. My version in js works fine, but on android I only get:

```
EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR: com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

```
socket = IO.socket(WEBSOCKET + "myChannel");
socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        socket.emit("myConnect", userinfo);
    }
    }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... arg0) {
        Log.e("EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR", arg0[0].toString());
    }
    }).on("something_changed", new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) args[0];
        Log.i("something_changed", obj.toString());
    }
});
socket.connect();
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. It was causing because of the internet access permission.

Add internet permission in your manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>`

It should work.